# Split tf dataset randomly in train and Test dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Is there a recommended way of randomly splitting a tf dataset into sub datasets with the dataset api? Right know I am using a generator function on about 150 Files which are about 1TB. I want to randomly split these datasets on read so I do not need to save these files again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sklearn's KFold function

```
class sklearn.model_selection.KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
```

> K-Folds cross-validator
>
> Provides train/test indices to split data in train/test sets. Split
>   dataset into k consecutive folds (without shuffling by default).
>
> Each fold is then used once as a validation while the k - 1 remaining
>   folds form the training set.

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
>>> kf.get_n_splits(X)
2
>>> print(kf)  
KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
>>> for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
...    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
...    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
...    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
TRAIN: [2 3] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
```

Comment: I know that this works well for numpy arrays but my dataset is way bigger then my ram so doing this will not work for me. I am trying to stay in the tf dataset ecosystem to gain performance

Answer (score 1):

There is no official recommendation from tf.data developers as such.
If you are looking for a small portion of your data as your validation data, you could use the [take()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take) and [skip()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#skip) functions to create a validation and train split.

```
val_dataset = dataset.take(num_elements)
train_dataset = dataset.skip(num_elements)
```

However, a good split would depend on a good shuffling, and for your case, you might be shuffling the files rather than the data as shuffling the data might be much more expensive so I am not sure of this approach.
Be aware of [reshuffle_each_iteration](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) parameter in shuffle so that you do not generate a different validation split when you iterate over the dataset many times.

An easier and consistent approach would be to have validation in a separate file/files so that you can read it in as a new dataset. But this might also not be a better idea depending on your application.

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of data coming in. 1 TB is probably small compared to what is coming next. I want to create the split on read so I don’t have to move the data around and wait a few hours every time I change a dataset split parameter. (Yes our servers are terrible ). I have thought about the skip and take method but it seems like a weird solution. Something like a random split operation which produces different datasets might be nicer. Of course this would mean that you always iterate over the whole dataset even if your split is just 1 %.

Comment: I see what you mean. There are a bunch of utility functions defined in [tf.contrib.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data)
You can probably define a bunch of datasets, sample from them using [sample_from_datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/sample_from_datasets), interleave them later in to a single dataset using [parallel_interleave](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/parallel_interleave).

Comment: It is a bit weird the dataset api does not have a well defined documentation on how to split datasets as it is the bread and butter of most applications.

Comment: Yea. The biggest problem is probably, that the splitting action depends heavily on the dataset you use. Therefore giving an official recommendation would probably produce more confusion then help